# I need help defining a variable from a joined table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulty defining a variable from a second table in a join.

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM Catalog
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Client_Data on CatalogMgr.partnumber = Client_Data.partnumber
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients on Client_Data.Client_id = Clients.Client_Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C1 on Clients.Client_Name = C1.Client_Name
        WHERE  Clients.Client_Id = '".$C_ID."'
        AND Avail_Flag = 10";

$CL_Name = Clients.Client_Name;
```

//Results
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

====On the output page

```
echo "$CL_Name";
```

is empty.

====I have tried

```
$CL_name = $row['Clients.Client_Name'];
$CL_name = $row['Client_Name'];
```

and all return an empty variable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am guessing the problems is because you only select the Catalog Table and not the Client Table where the Client_Name is.

Answer (score 0):

The first LEFT OUTER JOIN looks wrong.  `CatalogMgr` => `Catalog`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not select like this

```
$sql = "SELECT Catalog.* , Client_Data.name as `Client_Name`
FROM Catalog
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Client_Data on CatalogMgr.partnumber = Client_Data.partnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients on Client_Data.Client_id = Clients.Client_Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients C1 on Clients.Client_Name = C1.Client_Name
    WHERE  Clients.Client_Id = '".$C_ID."'
    AND Avail_Flag = 10";

   $CL_Name = Clients.Client_Name;
```

And with php echo like this

```
echo $row['Client_Name'];
```